# Bash Shell Scripting - displaying all files .c

Tags: command-line, bash

I need to display all the files with .c (C program files) in the terminal and having problems to do so.

My ideas were using `find` and `grep` and maybe `gcc`
But none of my attempts worked. I am working on Linux. I don't know the file names. I just want to list all the files.

I tried the following:

```
ls *.c
find . -type f *.c
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened do I need to write something else instead of 'name' thank you

Comment: `find` will only find files from `.` on, so depending on what folder you are in you might not find anything.  Try it as `find / -type f -name *.c` or change the `/` to the start of whatever folder you think they are all in like `~` or `/usr` or `/var`, etc.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED
Apparently there are no C program files! 
When I created one ls *.c worked even steeldriver answer thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
find . -type f -name '*.c'
```

If you want to search in a directory other than your current directory, use

```
find /desired/path/to/search -type f -name '*.c'
```

instead.

To explain what this command does, the first argument is the path for `find` to search for files in. Then `-type f` tells `find` to only consider regular files. `-name '*.c'` tells `find` to search for files whose names match the expression `*.c` (`*.c` is quoted to prevent the shell expanding the `*`).

If you wish to search case-insensitively, replace `-name '*.c'` with `-iname '*.c'` (then files with `.c` and `.C` file extensions will both be found).

By default, `find` will recursively search through all subdirectories of the directory provided. If you wish to limit the search depth, use the `-maxdepth` option.